# MapView viewForAnnotation show white pin in circle (default)

Tags: swift, mkmapview

When i do not set a delegate on `MKMapView` but add annotations, their images come up as the following:

[image: Default view]

However if i return a `MKAnnotationView` like so:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation.isKind(of: MKUserLocation.self) {
        return nil
    }

    guard annotation is MKPointAnnotation else { return nil }

    let identifier = "Annotation"
    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)

    if annotationView == nil {
        annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        annotationView!.collisionMode = .circle
        annotationView!.canShowCallout = true
    } else {
        annotationView!.annotation = annotation
    }

    return annotationView
}
```

Then the icons come out looking like a vertical pin:

[image: customised]

I know i can use a custom image on the `MKAnnotationView`. However, i want the default one, except i want it to look like the first rather than the second, but i also want to customise the callout. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first image belongs to an MKMarkerAnnotationView. So ask for that, instead of an MKPinAnnotationView.